# I want to connect between Java app and Xampp

Tags: java, mysql, database, xampp, connection

Enter code here:

[image: This my App and the Error:]

```
private static final String CONNECTION_PATH = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/parking";
```

The problem lies in the **connection path** and the **URL** of parking database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have the mysql JDBC driver available at runtime.

You need to get the JDBC driver on your classpath.

[This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-installing.html) may help ( no idea how current it is but it explains how to install the driver. )

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven, put

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

into your pom and you should be ready to go.

If you are not using maven, grab the jar file from http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/6.0.6/mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar and add it to your classpath.